# Can you say an object is a reference to a class?

Tags: java, class, reference

As part of my AP class I am learning objects, instances, references etc... So from what I understand a reference is a variable that points to something: a value, class etc . . . Therefore is it legal to say that a object is a reference to a class?

Note: I know this is subjective but I cant seem to find such a comparison anywhere else.

Comment: A reference is something that refers to an object...

Comment: An object contains within it a hidden (private to the JVM) reference/pointer to the class.  But the object is not a "reference" to the class.

Comment: It's not subjective.  An object is an instance of a class.  An object variable is a reference to an object.

Comment: (Everything is subjective, but it's the opinion of the instructor that counts.)

Answer (score 3):

By the usual definition of *reference* you can *not* say that. Correct would be "An object is an *instance* of a class.".

The usual definition of a *reference* is a value which points to a memory location that is usually occupied by some object. The difference between pointers and references is that you can do pointer arithmetics on the former but not on the latter.

For example in the following code snippet:

```
SomeClass o = new SomeClass();
SomeClass foo = o;
```

`SomeClass` is the class and `o` is a reference to the instance of `SomeClass` returned by this particular invocation of the `new` keyword. `new SomeClass()` allocates memory for a new instance of `SomeClass` and calls its constructor to initialize it. `foo` is another reference to the very same instance of `SomeClass` also referred to by `o`. In other words, `o` and `foo` point to the same object but are not the same reference.

Comment: int number = 27; so can you say number is a reference of int?

Comment: No, in `int number = 27` there are (at least in Java) no references involved because `int` is a primitive type. However, if you would have `Integer i = Integer.valueOf(27);` then `i` would be a reference to an `Integer` instance that represents the number `27`. Same would be true for `Integer i = new Integer(27);`. That's because `Integer` is a class and not a primitive type like `int`.

Comment: @someone: In other languages or other contexts, you might could argue that `number` is a reference to *an* int. But it's still not a reference to the *type* `int`; it's still just a reference to a specific *instance* of the type.  And you'd have to be crystal clear about the context; Java's typical use for the word "reference" would make your statement incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Object is not a reference of class, but instance of class.

Answer (score 1):

No, that would not be a valid statement. An object is an *instance* of a class, not a reference to one. When you have something like:

```
MyClass var = new MyClass();
```

Then `var` is a reference to the `MyClass` instance to which it was assigned (`new MyClass()`). This instance is in turn an *object*.

From [JLS §4.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1):

> An object is a class instance or an array.
>
> The reference values (often just *references*) are pointers to these objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.

Answer (score 1):

As somebody else said, a class is a like a blueprint. When you create an object based off of the class, the computer "builds" an object by allocating memory to create "parts" (variables) based off of your class.

Therefore, the object is not a reference to the class, implying that the object simply redirects you to the class.

The object is a instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

An object is really an instance of a class. Let's say we have the String class. An object of the type String is an *instance* of the String class, *not* that class itself. Given `String s="foo"`, `s`'s value would be a reference to an instance of the String class.

Now, every class has a `java.lang.Class` object that is associated with it, so `String.class` is a reference to an instance of java.lang.Class.

From JLS:

> An object is a class instance or an array.
>
> The reference values (often just *references*) are pointers to these objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.

Comment: Oops, I accidentally edited your answer because we have the same quote. Sorry - feel free to keep/remove the edit.

Comment: @arshajii No worries, it's fine. Sorry about the mix-up.

Answer (score 0):

No. That would be like saying that the scrambeled eggs you ate this morning are a reference to the abstract concept of scrambeled eggs.

Remember that a `class` is a blueprint, but it's not an actual, concrete object on its own. That only happens when you instantiate an object via the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object foo = new Object();
```

`foo` is an reference to a specific, concrete instance of the class `Object` but not to the class itself.

```
Class bar = Object.class;
```

`bar` is a reference to the `Object` class.

Comment: I suggest you use `Class bar` as the extra class involved in the generic type adds complexity beyond the original problem. Use of generics and parametrized types being correct can be saved for another discussion.

Comment: @hexafraction fair enough.  Removed for simplicity.